# Modify single vertex position in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am now in the middle of converting my code from OpenGL 2 where I was using `glBegin()`, `glVertex3f()` to OpenGL 3.3 and use of VBOs, EBOs. I read number of tutorials but I cannot find one very important thing and I hope someone would be able to help me here.

In previous version thanks to `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)` and 4 `glVertex3f(floa, float, float)` I was able to create shapes that I want. Or more precisely user wanted - he could just grab one of vertices and modify base rectangle. So it was possible to create something like this:

[image: previous]

Now my code for drawing base rectangle looks like this:

```
box_vertices[] = {
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f
};

box_indices[] = {
            0, 1, 3,
            1, 2, 3
};

GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(box_vertices), box_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(box_indices), box_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0); 

while(true) {
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "view");
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    model = glm::mat4();
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.25, 0.75, 1.0));
    // Position box at it's location
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

and the result looks something like this:

[image: now]

And maybe it might be helpful this is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

I just cannot find any idea how I can modify one vertex, because first it is embedded as I understand within VBO and second it has to be normalized to one as I understood (if it isn't OpenGL will do that for me). I doubt that I need each time generate new `box_vertices` array, so how it can be done?

Can someone please advice me how I can achieve my goal?

**EDIT:**

Modified code based on vesan's answer

```
while(true) {
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "view");
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(box_shader.Program, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    MakeSomeChangesToVerticesArray();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(box_vertices), box_vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    model = glm::mat4();
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.25, 0.75, 1.0));
    // Position box at it's location
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: If you can't do it using transformations, you can modify your buffer using `glBufferData` or `glBufferSubData`.

Comment: @vesan No, I can't with transformations unfortunately because it won't work in this case. Can you show simple example how I can use those methods?

Comment: @sebap123: What made you think that you have to "normalize" the values to so range. Vertex attributes are passed through to the shaders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply modify the data in your buffer(s). The data is still there, the VAO is only pointing to it.

So, at the beginning of your rendering cycle, simply modify your `box_vertices` array as desired, then call the same thing as when you're putting data in for the first time:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(box_vertices), box_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Your array is very small, so performance should not be a concern. If it is, be sure to only modify the buffer only if the shape has actually changed, consider using `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` instead of `GL_STATIC_DRAW` or use [glBufferSubData](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glBufferSubData.xml) to only replace a part of the buffer (I don't have a good example for this handy, unfortunately).

EDIT: The code to modify the buffer does not have to be inside the drawing loop, of course. It can be anywhere (for example in a mouse or keyboard handler). I suggested putting it inside the loop because the way the code is structured, there is nowhere else to place it.

Comment: I've modified code according to your answer. I guess this is exactly what you were saying - am I right?

Comment: One more thing I'm concerned about - if this values should be normalized (as I understood from tutorials), an I change let say one of the vertices coordinate to 5.0 and rest will stay this say, will it work?

Comment: Yes, that should work (have you tested it?). I would probably put the code to change the buffer before the `glBindVertexArray` call but I don't think it makes any difference. Not sure what you read about normalization, that is usually done for normals. Of course, if you modify your vertices to some wildly different values, your shape may end up offscreen.

Comment: Thank you very much for all explanations. I've tested it now and it works great.